# error BC36716: Visual Basic 9.0 does not support implicit line continuation in VB:NET in VS 2019

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, .net-3.5

I need to build Class Library (.dll) as a part of my custom IIS (SharePoint 2010) web service for .NET Framework **3.5**, but **VS2019** (Community edition) using VB.NET refuses me to build it with the subjected error.

I found suggestions to disable "**Pretty listing (reformatting) of code**" in Options > Text Editor > Basic Advanced (in settings of Visual Studio), but I found this functionality useful otherwise so I would prefer any different solution.

Another suggestion was about **deleting some "LangVersion"** (or similar) tag from .vbproj file, but I don't have there any ;-(

p.s. I had troubles with these in VS2015 and VS2017 as well...

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance. #JK

Comment: Where was this project first created? VB 9 was VS 2008. Have you considered just using explicit line continuation?

Comment: MSBuild has a rule for this in Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets (specific to SharePoint projects).  If the LangVersion is not specified and the project targets 3.5 then the LangVersion is forced to v9.0.  Same thing for C# projects btw, they get forced to v3.0.  So the problem is not that you can't find LangVersion, the problem is that it is *missing*.  Why this rule exists is murky, not enough comments in the .targets file.  So if you add LangVersion yourself then other things might go wrong.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure in which version of VS I started this project - it could really be in VS2008.

Comment: As I just tried when I re-create project from scratch in VS2019, I'm able to use continuation lines without any limitations ;-)

So, thank you for your comments, my problem is solved...

Best regards, #JK